# Get raw JSON Data of REST request in RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

I use RestSharp to access a Sever API.

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(serverUrl);

JObject parameters = new JObject
        {
           new JProperty("Param1", p1),
           new JProperty("Param2", p2)
        }; 

RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/Foo", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=UTF-8", parameters, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Is there a way to get the raw JSON Data of the REST request in RestSharp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this moment the answer is *no*. All parts of the actual request, including URL with query parameters, body and headers are only constructed in the `ConfigureHttp` private method.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, RestSharp has yet to provide a way to get the raw JSON Data of the request, but you can always use some web debugging proxy like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).